# Squares in a triquadratic field

Tags: nt.number-theory

I would like to know (as part of an attempt to streamline some calculations in the cohomology of a Morava stabiliser group) whether $1170\sqrt{-3}\sqrt{5}\sqrt{-7}-19110$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-7})$.  What is an efficient method for this kind of question?

Comment: Is its norm a square of an integer?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Which norm - the norm in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{105})$, or the norm in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{-7})$? In the former, no, if I haven't made a stupid error - the norm is $221457600$, which is not a square. In the latter, yes (in fact, it's a 4th power), but trivially (as its norm is $221457600^4$).

Comment: Ah, I see, the first norm not being a square does not imply anything.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I'm not entirely sure of that - the first norm not being a square implies that the second norm is not an 8th power, which I think should be sufficient for the question, though it may be more work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The field $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-7})$ has a lot of intermediate fields which we can exploit. Pick one of its index two subextensions, say $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{5})$. The element $\alpha=1170\sqrt{-3}\sqrt{5}\sqrt{-7}-19110$ of $L$ has as its only conjugate over $K$ the element $-1170\sqrt{-3}\sqrt{5}\sqrt{-7}-19110$, and so the norm of $\alpha$ with respect to the extension $L/K$ is $$N_{L/K}(\alpha)=-1170^2\cdot(-3)\cdot 5\cdot(-7)+19110^2=221457600 = 2^6\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\cdot13^3.$$
This norm is not a square in $K$ - for otherwise $K$ would ramify at $7$ and $13$. Therefore $\alpha$ is not a square in $L$.

This method should generalize quite nicely if you consider elements of the form $a+b\sqrt{n}$ inside a multiquadratic extension $L/\mathbb Q$, as picking a subfield  $K$ of index $2$ not containing $n$, the norm will be given by $a^2-bn^2$, and if the factorization of this integer contains some primes in odd exponents which do not ramify in $K$, you know it will not be a square in $K$. It probably won't always give you the right answer but it should work in many cases of interest.

Comment: A referee once berated me for writing "an index 2 subfield $K$ of $L$" instead of "a subfield $K$ over which $L$ is of degree 2". I still feel the former turn of phrase (while not standard terminology) is natural, and less cumbersome than the latter, and readily understood - glad to see I'm not alone... :)

Comment: @GNiklasch regardless of what your referee once said, I think it is awkward to refer to a *subfield* of $L$ the way Wojowu does, as "one of its index two extensions". For example, in $\mathbf C$ we wouldn't say $\mathbf R$ is an index two extension.  But the term "index two subextension" sounds okay in context.

Comment: @KConrad Completely agreed. I think "subextension" is the term my yesterday brain meant to use, so thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 10):

Set $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-7})$ and $\alpha = 1170\sqrt{-3}\sqrt{5}\sqrt{-7}-19110$.
I think the "best" way to show $\alpha$ is not a square in $K$ is *not* to show something else is not a square in a (smaller) number field, but to show something else is not a square in a finite field, and more precisely in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ for some prime $p$.  We'll wind up doing this with $p = 79$.

To prove $\alpha$ is not a square in $K$, or equivalently in $\mathcal O_K$, it suffices to find a (nonzero) prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $\mathcal O_K$ such that $\alpha \bmod \mathfrak p$ is not a square. There are many such $\mathfrak p$ if $\alpha$ is not a square: the Chebotarev density theorem implies that a nonsquare in $\mathcal O_K$ is not a square mod $\mathfrak p$ for a set of $\mathfrak p$ with density $1/2$ (natural density or Dirichlet density).  That means if such $\mathfrak p$ exist, it should not take very long to find one, just like for a nonsquare integer $b$ it should not take long to find a prime $p$ such that $b \bmod p$ is not a square (the set of such $p$ has density $1/2$).

How can we go about searching for a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ where $\alpha \bmod \mathfrak p$ is not a square? In practice it's a good idea to look for $\mathfrak p$ lying over a prime number $p$ that splits completely in $\mathcal O_K$ since then $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p \cong \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ and it's computationally easy to work in a field of prime order. The set of such $p$ has (natural) density $1/[K:\mathbf Q] = 1/8$ and $p$ splits completely in $K$ if and only if it splits completely in the quadratic fields $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3})$, $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{5})$, and $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{-7})$.  These splitting conditions are the congruences
$$
p \equiv 1 \bmod 3, \ \ 
p \equiv 1, 4 \bmod 5, \ \ 
p \equiv 1, 2, 4 \bmod 7.
$$
By the Chinese remainder theorem, these conditions correspond to six  congruence conditions mod $105$, which turn out to be
$$
p \equiv 1, 4, 16, 46, 64, 79 \bmod 105.
$$
The first prime fitting each of these six conditions is, respectively,
$$
211, \ \ 109, \ \ 331, \ \ 151, \ \ 379, \ \ 79.
$$
The smallest of these primes is $79$, so $79$ is the smallest prime splitting completely in $K$. Let's work with $p = 79$. Since it splits completely in $K$, there are $8$ primes $\mathfrak p_1, \ldots, \mathfrak p_8$ lying over $79$ in $\mathcal O_K$. For each $\mathfrak p_i$, $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p_i \cong \mathbf Z/79\mathbf Z$. We will reduce $\alpha$ modulo some of these $\mathfrak p_i$ until we find a nonsquare in $\mathbf Z/79\mathbf Z$. Since $1170 \equiv 64 \bmod 79$ and
$19110 \equiv 71 \bmod 79$, for each $\mathfrak p_i$ lying over $79$ we have
$$
\alpha \equiv 64\sqrt{-3}\sqrt{5}\sqrt{-7}-71 \bmod \mathfrak p_i.
$$

How can we describe the primes $\mathfrak p_i$?  The congruences
$a^2 \equiv -3 \bmod 79$, $b^2 \equiv 5 \bmod 79$, and $c^2 \equiv -7 \bmod 79$ each have two solutions: $a \equiv 32, 47 \bmod 79$,
$b \equiv 20, 59 \bmod 79$, and $c \equiv 25, 54 \bmod 79$.
Picking one solution for each of these three congruences mod $79$ distinguishes the $8$ different prime ideals $\mathfrak p_i$ from each other.

Example 1. There is a prime $\mathfrak p_1$ over $79$ where
$$
\sqrt{-3} \equiv 32 \bmod \mathfrak p_1, \ \ 
\sqrt{5} \equiv 20 \bmod \mathfrak p_1,  \ \ 
\sqrt{-7} \equiv 25 \bmod \mathfrak p_1.
$$
That makes
$$
\alpha \equiv 64(32)(20)(25)-71 \equiv 10 \bmod 79, 
$$
but $(\frac{10}{79}) = 1$ by quadratic reciprocity. Explicitly, $10 \equiv 22^2 \bmod 79$, so $\alpha \equiv 22^2 \bmod \mathfrak p_1$. That didn't work out as we had hoped.

Example 2. There is a prime $\mathfrak p_2$ over $79$ where
$$
\sqrt{-3} \equiv 47 \bmod \mathfrak p_2, \ \ 
\sqrt{5} \equiv 20 \bmod \mathfrak p_2,  \ \ 
\sqrt{-7} \equiv 25 \bmod \mathfrak p_2.
$$
That makes
$$
\alpha \equiv 64(47)(20)(25)-71 \equiv 6 \bmod 79, 
$$
and $(\frac{6}{79}) = -1$ by quadratic reciprocity. Thus $\alpha \bmod \mathfrak p_2$ is not a square, so $\alpha$ is not a square in $\mathcal O_K$ and we are done.

Answer (score 5):

A numerical approach: Let $x\sim\sqrt{1170\sqrt{105}-19110}$ be a numerical approximation of high precision (say 500 digits). Let $(b_1, \ldots, b_8)$ be a high precision numerical approximation of a $\mathbb Q$-basis of your number field. Run the PSLQ algorithm on the vector $(x, b_1, \ldots, b_8)$. If it finds a relation with small coefficients, this relation probably gives the expression of the square root in terms of a basis (a fact which is then easy to prove algebraically). If the result of the PSLQ algorithm is ugly, then $x$ is probably not a square.

With your example, PSLQ returned an ugly relation which proves that it is not a square of a simple element. (One has thus either to augment the numerical precision or to use a different approach).

In order to finish, we can use the fact that
PSLQ finds minimal polynomials of algebraic numbers:

Given a sufficiently precise numerical
approximation $X$ of a complex algebraic number $x$ of degree $d$,
use PSLQ with the vector $(\Re(X^j)+\pi\Im(X^j))_{j=0,\ldots,m}$ for $m\geq d$.
(Working with $\Re(X^j)+\pi\Im(X^j)$ is motivated by the fact that PSLQ uses real numbers.)
Using sufficient precision, that returns the coefficients of a multiple of a minimal polynomial for $x$.

Let us apply this to a good numerical approximation $X$ of
$$x=\sqrt{1170\sqrt{105}-19110}+\sqrt{-3}+\sqrt{-7}\ .$$

PSLQ suggests that we have $P(x)=0$ for
$$
\begin{align}
P &=& x^{16}
   &+ 152960x^{14} \\
&& &+ 9658087264x^{12} \\
&& &+ 325166174197760x^{10} \\
&& &+ 6314416898389255936x^8 \\
&& &+ 71963723574213583831040x^6 \\
&& &+ 472811869865588787137142784x^4 \\
&& &+ 1654975180084472905601718026240x^2 \\
&& &+ 2388696346634653834571599616475136.
\end{align}$$
This identity can be checked easily using
a computer algebra system. Since $P$ is indecomposable over $\mathbb Z[x]$, the number field $\mathbb Q[x]$ is of degree $16$ over $\mathbb Q$. This shows
$$\sqrt{1170\sqrt{105}-19110}\not\in\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{-7}].$$